# Accessing x+1 element with 'for x in list' in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse a new line delimited text file into blocks of lines, which are appended to a .txt file. I'd like to be able to grab x amount of lines AFTER my ending string, as these lines will vary in content, meaning setting the 'end string' to try to match it would miss lines.

Example of file:

```
"Start"
"..."
"..."
"..."
"..."
"---" ##End here
"xxx" ##Unique data here
"xxx" ##And here
```

And here's the code

```
first = "Start"
first_end = "---"

with open('testlog.log') as infile, open('parsed.txt', 'a') as outfile:
    copy = False
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip().startswith(first):
            copy = True
            outfile.write(line)
        elif line.strip().startswith(first_end):
            copy = False
            outfile.write(line)
            ##Want to also write next 2 lines here
        elif copy:
            outfile.write(line)
```

Is there any way to do this using `for line in infile`, or do I need to use a different type of loop?

Comment: I think you have to use a while loop over the iterator of lines here

Comment: Do you have an example of your file? The [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-continue-statement) statement could be an option too.

Comment: Added example of the file

Comment: `##Want to also write next 2 lines here` - try using something more clever for `copy` than a simple boolean, in order to control the behaviour of each run through the loop. For example, you could set it to be the number of lines that should be copied after the current point in the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `next` or `readline` (in Python 3 and up) to retrieve the next line in the file:

```
    elif line.strip().startswith(first_end):
        copy = False
        outfile.write(line)
        outfile.write(next(infile))
        outfile.write(next(infile))
```

or

```
    #note: not compatible with Python 2.7 and below
    elif line.strip().startswith(first_end):
        copy = False
        outfile.write(line)
        outfile.write(infile.readline())
        outfile.write(infile.readline())
```

This will also cause the file pointer to advance two additional lines, so the next iteration of `for line in infile:` will skip past the two lines you read with `readline`.

---

Bonus terminology nitpick: a file object is not a list, and methods for accessing the x+1th element of a list might not work for accessing the next line of a file, and vice versa. If you *did* want to access the next item of a proper list object, you could use `enumerate` so you can perform arithmetic on the list's index. For example:

```
seq = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux", "troz", "zort"]

#find all instances of "baz" and also the first two elements after "baz"
for idx, item in enumerate(seq):
    if item == "baz":
        print(item)
        print(seq[idx+1])
        print(seq[idx+2])
```

Note that, unlike `readline`, indexing will not advance the iterator, so `for idx, item in enumerate(seq):` will still iterate over "qux" and "troz".

---

An approach that works on *any* iterable is to use an additional variable to keep track of state across iterations. The advantage of this is that you don't have to know anything about how to manually advance iterables; the disadvantage is that reasoning about the logic within the loop is more difficult because it exposes an additional side-effect.

```
first = "Start"
first_end = "---"

with open('testlog.log') as infile, open('parsed.txt', 'a') as outfile:
    copy = False
    num_items_to_write = 0
    for line in infile:
        if num_items_to_write > 0:
            outfile.write(line)
            num_items_to_write -= 1
        elif line.strip().startswith(first):
            copy = True
            outfile.write(line)
        elif line.strip().startswith(first_end):
            copy = False
            outfile.write(line)
            num_items_to_write = 2
        elif copy:
            outfile.write(line)
```

---

In the specific case of pulling repetitive groups of data out of a delimited file, it might be appropriate to skip iteration entirely and use regex instead. For data like yours, that might look like:

```
import re

with open("testlog.log") as file:
    data = file.read()

pattern = re.compile(r"""
^Start$                 #"Start" by itself on a line
(?:\n.*$)*?             #zero or more lines, matched non-greedily
                        #use (?:) for all groups so `findall` doesn't capture them later
\n---$                  #"---" by itself on a line
(?:\n.*$){2}            #exactly two lines
""", re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)

#equivalent one-line regex:
#pattern = re.compile("^Start$(?:\n.*$)*?\n---$(?:\n.*$){2}", re.MULTILINE)

for group in pattern.findall(data):
    print("Found group:")
    print(group)
    print("End of group.\n\n")
```

When run on a log that looks like:

```
Start
foo
bar
baz
qux
---
troz
zort
alice
bob
carol
dave
Start
Fred
Barney
---
Wilma
Betty
Pebbles
```

... This will produce the output:

```
Found group:
Start
foo
bar
baz
qux
---
troz
zort
End of group.


Found group:
Start
Fred
Barney
---
Wilma
Betty
End of group.
```

Comment: This is what I'm trying to achieve, however, in practice, `outfile.write(infile.readline())` produces the error `ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data` on compilation

Comment: Interesting, that error does not occur on my machine. I'm guessing that mixing iteration and read methods is allowed in 3.X but not in 2.7. One solution is to convert your file to a list of lines with `lines = list(infile)` and use the list-based approach in my second code block. I will compose a second approach in a minute.

Comment: @chepner, oh, that's surprising to me. Good observation :-) I wonder why one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: I guess `next` goes through iterator's API, so it's not consider side effect to the iterator fields, while `readline()` is clearly having unintended side effect during iteration.

Comment: Probably an implementation detail that wasn't considered worth fixing until Python 3 replaced the `file` type with `BytesIO` and `TextIO` from the `io` module.

Answer (score 2):

easiest would be to make a generator function parsing the infile:

```
def read_file(file_handle, start_line, end_line, extra_lines=2):
    start = False
    while True:
        try:
            line = next(file_handle)
        except StopIteration:
            return

        if not start and line.strip().startswith(start_line):
            start = True
            yield line
        elif not start:
            continue
        elif line.strip().startswith(end_line):
            yield line
            try:
                for _ in range(extra_lines):
                    yield next(file_handle)
            except StopIteration:
                return
        else:
            yield line
```

The `try-except` clauses would not be needed if you know each file is well-formed.

You can use this generator like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    first = "Start"
    first_end = "---"

    with open("testlog.log") as infile, open("parsed.txt", "a") as outfile:
        output = read_file(
            file_handle=infile,
            start_line=first,
            end_line=first_end,
            extra_lines=1,
        )
        outfile.writelines(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation of @Kevin answer with a 3-state variable and less code duplication.

```
first = "Start"
first_end = "---"
# Lines to read after end flag
extra_count = 2

with open('testlog.log') as infile, open('parsed.txt', 'a') as outfile:
    # Do no copy by default
    copy = 0

    for line in infile:
        # Strip once only
        clean_line = line.strip()

        # Enter "infinite copy" state
        if clean_line.startswith(first):
            copy = -1

        # Copy next line and extra amount
        elif clean_line.startswith(first_end):
            copy = extra_count + 1

        # If in a "must-copy" state
        if copy != 0:
            # One less line to copy if end flag passed
            if copy > 0:
                copy -= 1
            # Copy current line
            outfile.write(line)
```